# insert into tables using select and values in SQL Server CE

Tags: select, sql-server-ce

I have a query in which the syntax is correct (verified using SQL Server), but when I execute it for SQL Server CE, it gives the following error:

```
insert into HistoryPC (Date, Col1) 
values ('12/02/2012', (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN i.ProductCode = 'XXX' and i.ProductCode = p.ProductCode THEN Quantity END) 
                       FROM Product p, Invoice_Details i 
                       left outer join Invoice_Header h on h.Invoice_NO = i.Invoice_No  
                       WHERE h.Date = '2012-06-02'))
```

Error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 63,Token in error = SELECT ]

What I want is to insert the date column of the table to be Today and other values using select.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you mixing old-style and new-style joins?

Comment: Are you sure the CE engine has the same parser/executor as the full-blown sql server? Just because they share similarities in naming doens't mean they'll actually work the same.

Comment: sql CE has lot of limitations compared to sql server. I think sql ce does not support this kind of insert. Is there a way I can  insert the date column of the table to be Today and other values using select.

Comment: If you want it to be today, why do you have the string '12/02/2012' instead of using GETDATE()?

Answer (score 1):

The query doesn't make sense to me as written. Here is the closest I could get to what you wrote, but I suspect it isn't what you meant.

```
insert into HistoryPC (Date,Col1) 
SELECT '12/02/2012',
  SUM(CASE WHEN i.ProductCode = 'XXX' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END)
FROM Product AS p 
INNER JOIN Invoice_Details AS i
ON i.ProductCode = p.ProductCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice_Header AS h 
ON h.Invoice_NO = i.Invoice_No 
AND h.Date = '2012-06-02';
```